# Background appears only once

Tags: jquery

I am asking to help solve the following issue. 
https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrn7wv7/

When you want to add a new tab (clicking on a tab with “+” sign) a popup window with dark background appears.
If you then add more tabs the popup appears without any background. 
Thus, the dark background appears only first time you call the popup window.
I guess smth wrong goes inside these lines (lines 4-25 in JS FIddle):

```
$("#tab_0").click(function () {
    $("#popup__bgr").fadeIn(300,
        function () {
            $("#popup").css("display", "block").animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200);
        });
    $(function () {
        $("#inputName").val("");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be removing whole `style` attribute where you're closing popup

```
$( "#popup__bgr" ).fadeOut( 200 ).removeAttr('style'); // add .removeAttr()
```

because `popup__bgr` div is having an `opacity` of `0` when you open and close popup after first time that is causing the problem for the same.

**OR**

Remove `opacity:0 and top:45%` at following line wherever it repeats see in demo 2

```
$( "#popup__bgr" ).animate(// Remove opacity:0 and top:45% keep the rest
```

### [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrn7wv7/4/)

### [**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrn7wv7/)